# Stripe RoR - undefined method `encoding' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

So I have an if statement. If a customer exists return false. I was trying with an actual customer id but it was throwing an error, I replaced it with a 1. Still getting that error.

```
if Stripe::Customer.retrieve(1)
```

throws

```
undefined method `encoding' for 1:Fixnum
```

link to the api :

https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer

Comment: try pass String `Stripe::Customer.retrieve("1")`

Comment: irb(main):005:0> "1".respond_to?('encoding')
=> true

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was

```
require "stripe"
```

... :|

Comment: Where did you added `require "stripe"`? I'm having the same issue when processing a card... `undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#customers

There you can find that, in attributes it takes

```
id: string
```

So the code should be

```
#Stripe::Customer.retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID})
Stripe::Customer.retrieve(1.to_s)
```

Hope it will work.